# python iterate over dictionary emptys it

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code I'm analyzing. But I've found that iterating over a dictionary empties it. I've fixed the problem by by making a deepcopy of the dictionary and iterating over that in some code that displays the values, then later use the original dictionary to iterate over that to assign values to a 2D array. Why does iterating over the original dictionary to display it empty it, so that later use of the dictionary is unusable since it is now empty? Any replies welcome.

```
import copy

# This line fixed the problem
trans = copy.deepcopy(transitions)

print ("\nTransistions  = ")
# Original line was:
#  for state, next_states in transitions.items():
# Which empties the dictionary, so not usable after that

for state, next_states in trans.items():
    for i in next_states:
        print("\nstate = ", state, " next_state = ", i)

# Later code which with original for loop showed empty dictionary
for state, next_states in transitions.items():
    for next_state in next_states:
        print("\n one_step trans  state = ", state, " next_state = ", next_state)
        one_step[state,next_state] += 1
```

A print of the dictionary:

```
Transistions  = 
{0: <map object at 0x0000000003391550>, 1: <map object at 0x00000000033911D0>, 2: <map object at 0x0000000003391400>, 3: <map object at 0x00000000033915F8>, 4: <map object at 0x0000000003391320>}
```

Type:

```
Transistions  = 
<class 'dict'>
```

Edit: Here's the code that uses map. Any suggestions on how to edit it to created the dictionary without using map?

```
numbers = dict((state_set, n) for n, state_set in enumerate(sets))

transitions = {}
for state_set, next_sets in state_set_transitions.items():
    dstate = numbers[state_set]
    transitions[dstate] = map(numbers.get, next_sets)
```

Comment: Iterating over a dict does not empty it. You have some other bug.

Comment: What's the type of `transitions`? Are you sure it's a dictionary? Try `print(type(transitions))` and paste the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a dict doesn't empty it. Iterating over a **map iterator** empties it.

Wherever you generated your `transitions` dict, you should have used a list comprehension instead of `map` to create lists instead of iterators for the values:

```
[whatever for x in thing]
```

instead of

```
map(lambda x: whatever, thing)
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'm analyzing some code somebody else created so I've noticed in other parts of the code he/she used a map. Maybe that person shouldn't have. I'll see if I can edit the code to generate the dictionary as you explained. Would there be any differences in the code and performance if I do as you suggest?

Comment: @te7: The code differences would be simple, looking like what I've shown above. There will be performance differences; positive or negative, you shouldn't worry about them. It's essentially never meaningful to compare the performance of working code and wrong code.